AppImage 'symbol lookup error' in libc library
I created a AppImage file on a system but cant run on other system.
I get the following error:
$LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$APPDIR/usr/lib/libc.so.6 ./Programik-x86_64.AppImage  /tmp/.mount_PrograVkCV6J/usr/bin/p: symbol lookup error: /tmp/.mount_PrograVkCV6J/usr/bin/../lib/libc.so.6: undefined symbol: _dl_audit_symbind_alt, version GLIBC_PRIVATE
sometimes I get:
/tmp/.mount_PrograYCt79i/usr/bin/p: symbol lookup error: /tmp/.mount_PrograYCt79i/usr/bin/../lib/libpthread.so.0: undefined symbol: _dl_make_stack_executable, version GLIBC_PRIVATE 
LD_DEBUG=libs ./my-prog.AppImage output is same, refer here https://pastebin.com/9ACH9Y41
When I create the package i get the followingg logs:
Skipping deployment of blacklisted library /lib64/libm.so.6 

Skipping deployment of blacklisted library /lib64/libc.so.6 

Skipping deployment of blacklisted library /lib64/libpthread.so.0 

Skipping deployment of blacklisted library /lib64/librt.so.1 

Skipping deployment of blacklisted library /lib64/libgmp.so.10 

Skipping deployment of blacklisted library /lib64/libdl.so.2 

How to create an AppImage correctly?
All libraries listed from ldd of my program are inside in /usr/lib and copied in my project AppImage.
I use appimagetool and linuxdeploy to create the AppImage.
I can't use static libraries.


I get the following error:

You are doing to wrong. First, LD_LIBRARY_PATH should point to a directory, not a library.
Second, setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to select a different version of GLIBC doesn't work for reasons explained here.
